# sigsegv при записи в файл

Tags: c++, fstream

При попытке записи в файл получаю ошибку segmentation failed (core dumped)

```
        std::string filename{"output"};
        std::fstream savef;
        int ver{1};
        savef.open(filename,std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::trunc);
        savef.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(ver),sizeof(ver)); //Здесь выбивает ошибку (если верить gdb)
```

Comment: int к char*? Может хотя б int* к char*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь скастить `int` (который обычно 4 байта) к указателю на `char*` который обычно 8 байт. А потом по этому адресу (в котором в меньших 4 байтах записано 1, в старших - кто его знает), прочитать 4 байта. То, что оно просто падает - это ещё хорошо.

Но если уже так писать, то где то так

```
savef.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&ver),sizeof(ver));
```

Comment: А как тогда поступить со значениями из функций?

Comment: приведите пример того, что Вы хотите сделать, а я попробую предложить код

Comment: `class someclass{
    int getSomeValue(){
        return 10;
    }
};

int main(){
someclass some;
savef.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(some.getSomeValue()),sizeof(some.getSomeValue())); 
}`

Comment: сохраните в переменную. А дальше проблема решена.